# Other way to see average standard error in cross validation between model for geostatistical layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

Is there another way to compare average standard error in geostatistical wizard between model type? It seem not relevant to generate one by one the geostatistical layer to compare each model type just to see the lowest error.